# Performance: Creating a relationship in neo4j based on property ID

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For test purposes i imported data from another datasource into neo4j.
I imported the data only as nodes. Now i want to add the edges based on the imported ID. Every node has 2 fields

- id: contains the identification as String
- from: contains all connections as a String[]

For performance improvements i also created an index for the propertiy "id" and an index for the property "from"

First i created both properties as String (the from list as comma separated String).

This works, but is really slow:

```
MATCH (e:Test1),(r:Test2)
WHERE r.from CONTAINS e._id
MERGE (e)-[:HAS]->(r)
```

is there a better way?

PS: i tried also to store the from field as String[]. than i used the following query

```
MATCH (e:Test1),(r:Test2)
WHERE e._id IN r.from
MERGE (e)-[:HAS]->(r)
```

-> Performance is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you take a combination of all components - the Cartesian product. In both cases. More would be better to [split the string by comma](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/#functions-split) to identifiers. For example:

```
MATCH (T2:Test2)
UNWIND split(T2.from, ",") as id
MATCH (T1:Test1) WHERE T1._id = id
MERGE (T1)-[:HAS]->(T2)
```

Or, if you keep the identifiers in the array:

```
MATCH (T2:Test2)
UNWIND T2.from as id
MATCH (T1:Test1) WHERE T1._id = id
MERGE (T1)-[:HAS]->(T2)
```

And, of course, do not forget about the index.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, at import time, you should be creating the `:HAS` relationships instead of creating the `from` property (which forces you to make a wasteful additional query to create the relationships, and leaves you with redundant `from` properties that you would probably want to delete).

For example, if you are using `LOAD CSV` to import, and your import file has `test2Id` and `from` columns (a string and a string collection, respectively), this import query should create all the nodes and relationships:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///input.csv" AS row
MERGE (t2:Test2 {id: row.test2Id})
WITH row, t2
UNWIND row.from AS t1Id
MERGE (t1:Test1 {id: t1Id})
MERGE (t1)-[:HAS]->(t2);
```

For better performance, you would want indexes on both `:Test1(id)` and `:Test2(id)`.

Comment: the problem in my use case is: It is not sure if all id / from relations are valid to a given time. the data source has no concept of transaction or valid references. so i am forced to have a 'async' edge/node creation